# 302 Moved Temporarily 15ms

Tags: php, jquery, email

i have following php code

```
      if(mail($ToEmail, $Subject, $Content, $Headers) == false) {
         echo "Error While Sending Email to : ".$ToEmail;
         }else{ 
         echo "Email Send Successfully to: ".$ToEmail; ;
         }
```

i call this php code from jquery like this

```
       var uemail="abc@domain.com,xyz@domain.com,gty@domain.com";

         uemail = uemail.split(',');

var interval;
var counter = 0;
var check = function() { 
                        if(counter < uemail.length) {
                            // Send email post 
                            counter++; 
                        } else {
                            clearInterval(interval);
                        }
            };

interval = setInterval(check,10000);
```

after 2nd time execution its shows 302 Moved Temporarily 15ms in firebug and user loogoff

Thanks

Comment: Not enough information. You will probably have to show the full PHP code.

Comment: Well, more PHP code may help, but you're also not showing /anything/ about how the JS is calling PHP (presumably some kind of AJAX).

Answer (score 1):

The error that you're getting is thrown client side when the AJAX callback method does not receive the response it expected.

If there is a timeout then a 302 will be thrown by AJAX. I believe anything other than a 200 response triggers a 302 too.

To test what is wrong try adding something similar to this in your JavaScript:

```
if(responseText.indexOf('<body') != -1) {

// a 302 redirection happened
}
```